# Curious why some cells are shown in a different Z index in View Debugger in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I was in the view debugger...debugging, and I was curious why certain cells seem to have a different Z index from the rest. I've seen this before but decided to ask about it. Is this just an Xcode, view debugger thing? Or is this actually what's happening?[image: Viewing App in Xcode View Debugger]

I'm actually not too sure what the best way to find out is because sometimes it looks nice and flat like this image: .[image]

Thanks!

Comment: I think this is just the way Xcode chooses to visualize them, I don't think they have a different "z-index"

Comment: That's what I thought and that would make sense. Wasn't sure if there might have been something I didn't know here. Thanks for replying!